# Parsing the Hugging Face Transformer Output

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am looking to use `bert-english-uncased-finetuned-pos` transformer, mentioned here

https://huggingface.co/vblagoje/bert-english-uncased-finetuned-pos?text=My+name+is+Clara+and+I+live+in+Berkeley%2C+California.

I am querying the transformer this way...

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vblagoje/bert-english-uncased-finetuned-pos")

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("vblagoje/bert-english-uncased-finetuned-pos")

text = "My name is Clara and I live in Berkeley, California."
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(text + '</s>', return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(input_ids)
```

But the `outputs` is coming something like this

> (tensor([[[-1.8196e+00, -1.9783e+00, -1.7416e+00,  1.2082e+00,
> -7.0337e-02,
> -7.0322e-03,  3.4300e-01, -9.6914e-01, -1.3546e+00,  7.7266e-03,
> 3.7128e+00, -3.4061e-01,  4.8385e+00, -1.2548e+00, -5.1845e-01,
> 7.0140e-01,  1.0394e+00],
> [-1.2702e+00, -1.5518e+00, -1.1553e+00, -4.4077e-01, -9.8661e-01,
> -3.2680e-01, -6.5338e-01, -3.9779e-01, -7.5383e-01, -1.2677e+00,
> 9.6353e+00,  1.9938e-01, -1.0282e+00, -7.5071e-01, -1.0307e+00,
> -8.0589e-01,  4.2073e-01],
> [-9.6988e-01, -5.0090e-01, -1.3858e+00, -1.0554e+00, -1.4040e+00,
> -7.5977e-01, -7.4156e-01,  8.0594e+00, -5.1854e-01, -1.9098e+00,
> -1.6362e-02,  1.0594e+00, -8.4962e-01, -1.7415e+00, -1.0628e+00,
> -1.7485e-01, -1.1490e+00],
> [-1.4368e+00, -1.6313e-01, -1.3202e+00,  8.7465e+00, -1.3782e+00,
> -9.8889e-01, -1.1371e+00, -1.0917e+00, -9.8495e-01, -9.3237e-01,
> -9.6111e-01, -4.1658e-01, -7.3133e-01, -9.6004e-01, -9.5337e-01,
> 3.1836e+00, -8.3462e-01],
> [-7.9476e-01, -7.9640e-01, -9.0027e-01, -6.9506e-01, -8.9706e-01,
> -6.9383e-01, -3.1590e-01,  1.2390e+00, -1.0443e+00, -9.9977e-01,
> -8.8189e-01,  8.7941e+00, -9.9445e-01, -1.2076e+00, -1.1424e+00,
> -9.7801e-01,  5.6683e-01],
> [-8.2837e-01, -5.5060e-01, -2.1352e-01, -8.8721e-01,  9.5536e+00,
> 1.0478e+00, -5.6208e-01, -7.1037e-01, -7.0248e-01,  1.1298e-01
>
> ...
>
> -7.3788e-01,  4.3640e-03,  1.6994e+00,  1.1528e-01, -1.0983e+00,
> -8.9202e-01, -1.2869e+00,  4.9141e+00, -6.2096e-01,  4.8374e+00,
> 3.2384e-01,  4.6213e-01],
> [-1.3622e+00,  2.0772e+00, -1.6680e+00, -8.8679e-01, -8.6959e-01,
> -1.7468e+00, -1.1424e+00,  1.6996e+00,  3.5800e-01, -4.3927e-01,
> -3.6129e-01, -4.2220e-01, -1.7912e+00,  8.0154e-01,  7.4594e-01,
> -1.0620e+00,  3.8152e+00],
> [-1.2889e+00, -2.9379e-01, -1.6543e+00, -4.3326e-01, -2.4919e-01,
> -4.0112e-01, -4.4255e-01,  2.2697e-01, -4.6042e-01, -3.7862e-03,
> -6.3061e-01, -1.3280e+00,  8.5533e+00, -4.6881e-01,  2.3882e+00,
> 2.4533e-01, -1.4095e-01],
> [-9.5640e-01, -5.7213e-01, -1.0245e+00, -5.3566e-01, -1.5287e-01,
> -6.6977e-01, -5.3392e-01, -3.1967e-02, -7.3077e-01, -3.1048e-01,
> -7.2973e-01, -3.1701e-01,  1.0196e+01, -5.2346e-01,  4.0820e-01,
> -2.1350e-01,  1.0340e+00]]], grad_fn=),)

But as per the documentation, I am expecting output to be in a JSON format...

> [   {
> "entity_group": "PRON",
> "score": 0.9994694590568542,
> "word": "my"   },   {
> "entity_group": "NOUN",
> "score": 0.997125506401062,
> "word": "name"   },   {
> "entity_group": "AUX",
> "score": 0.9938186407089233,
> "word": "is"   },   {
> "entity_group": "PROPN",
> "score": 0.9983252882957458,
> "word": "clara"   },   {
> "entity_group": "CCONJ",
> "score": 0.9991229772567749,
> "word": "and"   },   {
> "entity_group": "PRON",
> "score": 0.9994894862174988,
> "word": "i"   },   {
> "entity_group": "VERB",
> "score": 0.9983153939247131,
> "word": "live"   },   {
> "entity_group": "ADP",
> "score": 0.999370276927948,
> "word": "in"   },   {
> "entity_group": "PROPN",
> "score": 0.9987357258796692,
> "word": "berkeley"   },   {
> "entity_group": "PUNCT",
> "score": 0.9996636509895325,
> "word": ","   },   {
> "entity_group": "PROPN",
> "score": 0.9985638856887817,
> "word": "california"   },   {
> "entity_group": "PUNCT",
> "score": 0.9996631145477295,
> "word": "."   } ]

What am I doing wrong? How can I parse the current output to the desired JSON output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see there is the proprietary inference API from huggingface. This API is not part of the transformers library, but you can build something similar. All you need is the [Tokenclassificationpipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#tokenclassificationpipeline):

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification, TokenClassificationPipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vblagoje/bert-english-uncased-finetuned-pos")

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("vblagoje/bert-english-uncased-finetuned-pos")
p = TokenClassificationPipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
p('My name is Clara and I live in Berkeley, California.')
```

Output:

```
[{'word': 'my', 'score': 0.9994694590568542, 'entity': 'PRON', 'index': 1},
 {'word': 'name', 'score': 0.9971255660057068, 'entity': 'NOUN', 'index': 2},
 {'word': 'is', 'score': 0.9938186407089233, 'entity': 'AUX', 'index': 3},
 {'word': 'clara', 'score': 0.9983252882957458, 'entity': 'PROPN', 'index': 4},
 {'word': 'and', 'score': 0.9991229772567749, 'entity': 'CCONJ', 'index': 5},
 {'word': 'i', 'score': 0.9994894862174988, 'entity': 'PRON', 'index': 6},
 {'word': 'live', 'score': 0.9983154535293579, 'entity': 'VERB', 'index': 7},
 {'word': 'in', 'score': 0.999370276927948, 'entity': 'ADP', 'index': 8},
 {'word': 'berkeley',
  'score': 0.9987357258796692,
  'entity': 'PROPN',
  'index': 9},
 {'word': ',', 'score': 0.9996636509895325, 'entity': 'PUNCT', 'index': 10},
 {'word': 'california',
  'score': 0.9985638856887817,
  'entity': 'PROPN',
  'index': 11},
 {'word': '.', 'score': 0.9996631145477295, 'entity': 'PUNCT', 'index': 12}]
```

You can find the other available pipelines which might be used by the inference API [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#pipelines).

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there any documentation on how can one use other similar proprietary models? Would be good if you can include that, will be helpful for everyone.

Comment: @red-devil I have added a link to the documentation of the other pipelines.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Realised as you commented.